# Using Multi-lingual message from locale folder

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to access multi-lingual messages from locale folder.

This is a message file I have in my locale folder

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
MY_MESSAGE = _('Session time out.')
```

and im using it In my View.py like below - it works !!

```
import text_messages
messages.error(request, text_messages.MY_MESSAGE)
```

Is there anyway to use the same in my tempaltes (HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation offers all the necessary information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/

After you have enabled translations the way you want, you can access translated content in your templates by loading the i18n tag:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

And using the appropriate tag:

```
{% trans "my message" %}
```

If "my message" is translated:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files

It will display it's translation to the currently used language.